# helm_release nginx-ingress-controller renames digitalocean_loadbalancer name

Tags: nginx, terraform, kubernetes-helm, load-balancing, digital-ocean

I have terraform config that creates digitalocean_loadbalancer and then creates helm_release with nginx-ingress-controller chart.

The first part:

```
resource "digitalocean_loadbalancer" "do_lb" {
  name   = "do-lb"
  region = "ams3"
  size = "lb-small"
  algorithm = "round_robin"
  redirect_http_to_https = true

  forwarding_rule {
    entry_port     = 80
    entry_protocol = "http"

    target_port     = 80
    target_protocol = "http"
  }

  forwarding_rule {
    entry_port     = 443
    entry_protocol = "https"

    target_port     = 443
    target_protocol = "https"
    tls_passthrough = true
  }
}
```

it creates loadbalancer with name "do-lb" successfully.

Then, after applying helm_release

```
resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress_chart" {
  name       = "nginx-ingress-controller"
  namespace  = "default"
  repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart      = "nginx-ingress-controller"
  set {
    name  = "service.type"
    value = "LoadBalancer"
  }
  set {
    name  = "service.annotations.kubernetes\\.digitalocean\\.com/load-balancer-id"
    value = digitalocean_loadbalancer.do_lb.id
  }
  depends_on = [
    digitalocean_loadbalancer.do_lb,
  ]
}
```

it automatically renames the loadbalancer name to something md5-like.

The question is how to prevent such renaming?

Comment: Do you need the URN instead? Or you know it's the `id` that needs to be used but the value is in a wrong format?

Comment: I want to be able to set name of created load balancer by helm_release nginx-ingress-controller. Currently it is just randomly looking hash for loadbalancer name.

Comment: Actually, after testing with just helm_release (without separate digitalocean_loadbalancer resource) it still creates load balancer (which is correct) but the naming still is random hash. Could not find the naming reference for load balancer.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to provide the [`service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-name` annotation](https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager/blob/master/docs/controllers/services/annotations.md#servicebetakubernetesiodo-loadbalancer-name).

> Specifies a custom name for the Load Balancer. Existing Load Balancers will be renamed. The name must adhere to the following rules:
>
> - it must not be longer than 255 characters
> - it must start with an alphanumeric character
> - it must consist of alphanumeric characters or the '.' (dot) or '-' (dash) characters
> - except for the final character which must not be '-' (dash)
>
> If no custom name is specified, a default name is chosen consisting of the character a appended by the Service UID.

Your case:

```
resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress_chart" {
  name       = "nginx-ingress-controller"
  namespace  = "default"
  repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
  chart      = "nginx-ingress-controller"
  set {
    name  = "service.type"
    value = "LoadBalancer"
  }
  set {
    name  = "service.annotations.kubernetes\\.digitalocean\\.com/load-balancer-id"
    value = digitalocean_loadbalancer.do_lb.id
  }
  set {
    name  = "service.annotations.kubernetes\\.digitalocean\\.com/load-balancer-name"
    value = "do-lb"
  }
  depends_on = [
    digitalocean_loadbalancer.do_lb,
  ]
}
```